# How to mirror the left side of an 1d numpy array with variable length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

With a given 1d numpy array I would like to mirror the left part on the right hand side of the array. So given `[1,2,3,4]` the output should be `[1,2,2,1]`. This should work for different lengths of arrays, always mirroring at the midpoint, i.e. `[1,2,3,4,5]` should yield `[1,2,3,2,1]`.

This feels as if there is a nice one-liner in numpy but with different lengths it trips up and so I could only come up with this helper function:

```py
def mirror_left(arr):
    """ Mirrors the left/up part of an array. """
    if len(arr) % 2 == 0:
        arr[len(arr)//2:] = arr[len(arr)//2 - 1::-1]
    else:
        arr[len(arr)//2:] = arr[len(arr)//2::-1]
    return arr

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

print(mirror_left(a))
print(mirror_left(b))
```

Which gives the correct output: `[1 2 3 2 1]` and `[1 2 3 3 2 1]` but looks contrived.

Is there a better way for mirroring / copying the left half onto the right half of an array?

Comment: You could do: `n = len(a) // 2` then `a[-n:] = a[n-1::-1]`. Obvious substitution for `n` to make it a one-liner, but I don't think that would add readability.

Comment: For small arrays, `arr[arr.size//2:] = arr[(arr.size-1)//2::-1]` is simpler and just slightly faster. For big array, this is very hard to beat Numpy in Python... You could write a faster code in C (about 50~60% faster on x86/x86-64 PC platforms) but probably not directly in Python. The reason is that Numpy almost saturates the RAM bandwidth (unless you run your code on a server with many cores) although it does not do it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Take care of your assignment, your expression `arr[len(arr)//2:] = arr[len(arr)//2 - 1::-1]` modify your array in place. As you return `arr`, I think you don't want to modify the original array but get a copy of it?

You can use this:

```
def merge_left(arr):
    return np.concatenate([arr[:len(arr)//2 + len(arr)%2], arr[len(arr)//2 - 1::-1]])
```

Output:

```
>>> merge_left(a)
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1])

>>> merge_left(b)
array([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: The point is that an out-of-place reverse is much more expensive because a new buffer needs to be allocated and filled. This is *3 times slower* than the original code on big arrays (with 100M items) on my machine (and not much better for small ones). The OP may have done this choice for the sake of performance.

Comment: I'm agree but as I said, I think the OP wants to return a copy.